# Get selected dropdown value in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I have the below dropdown value in html and I am sending data to servlet using a `GET` method:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

In servlet, when I do
`request.getParameter("country");` I am getting IN, AU and US
instead of real country name

Comment: Obviously the values are passed to the servlet. Either change the option values or map the values to the full country names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<select name="country">
<option>India</option>
<option>Australia</option>
<option>United States</option>
</select>
```

Instead.

Or use the direct BCP47-Code (https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)

```
 Locale.forLanguageTag(request.getParameter("country"))
    .getDisplayCountry(Locale.forLanguageTag("en_US"));
```

Page 4 sais 2 ALPHA-Characters are minimum for locale:

> language      = 2*3ALPHA            ; shortest ISO 639 code

Answer (score 0):

Remove Value from option, it will work fine.

```
String country = request.getParameter("country");
out.print(country);
```