# How do I get the displayed value from a dropdown that returns an id?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, dropdown

Hey I'm using jsp and servlets. Here is my dropdown

```
<label>Disposition: </label>
        <select name="petDisposition" id="petDisposition">            
            <c:forEach items="${dispoList}" var="dispoList">
                 <option value="${dispoList.dispoId}" ${dispoList.dispoId == dispoId ? 
"selected='selected'" : ""}>
                    <c:out value="${dispoList.longDesc}"/></option>
                </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select><br>
```

In my servlet I call it using

```
String petDisposition = request.getParameter("petDisposition");
```

I can only return it as a number. How do I get the displayed text from this?

Comment: You already have it in the list behind `${dispoList}`. Just grab from it.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you searching a little bit more first before posting a question.

You could just erase the value from your option. You are setting the value ${dispoList.dispoId} as a value and the selected option sends that value to your servlet.

You could change the value to the text you want to get, if you have a method/field with the text in your dispoList `<option value="${dispoList.myText}">`

See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627631/get-selected-dropdown-value-in-servlet) and please also [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840655/how-get-selected-option-label-from-a-dropdown-list])

The second link will you help you with a better design for this.

Comment: Sending more data via forms than necessary is inefficient.